# Why Date is not displayed in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Model

```
    date =models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in my django model.py file and everything is working fine but the problem is it won't show data/time in django admin panel.

Here Date is created as an auto_now_add=True but it not showing in an Admin Panel

Comment: please show models.py with your model

Answer (score 0):

The `auto_now_add` fields are read-only and not displayed in the Django admin panel by default. But you can add them to your admin panel by adding them in your `admin.py`.

in your case will be like this:

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('date',)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```